# CMake regex match directories in list

Tags: regex, list, cmake

So I have list of files (or values) like this

```
set(HEADER_FILES DirA/header1.h DirA/header2.hpp
                DirB/header3.h DirB/stuff.hpp)
```

Then how do I get sub list of files only in DirA ? I'm using CMake 2.8.x and I tired regex match:

```
string(REGEX MATCHALL "DirA/(.+)" DirA_FILES ${HEADER_FILES})
```

But result is just copy of the orginal string like: "DirA/header1.h DirA/header2.hpp DirB/header3.h DirB/stuff.hpp" or nothing.

Well again as always, while writing this question I solved it:

```
set(SubListMatch)
foreach(ITR ${HEADER_FILES})
    if(ITR MATCHES "(.*)DirA/(.*)")
        list(APPEND SubListMatch ${ITR})
    endif()
endforeach()
```

But CMake is quite new thing to me so how do I wrap that code into function? I have never written any CMake functions so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn it into a function like this:

```
# Define function
function(GetSubList resultVar)
  set(result)
  foreach(ITR ${ARGN})  # ARGN holds all arguments to function after last named one
    if(ITR MATCHES "(.*)DirA/(.*)")
      list(APPEND result ${ITR})
    endif()
  endforeach()
  set(${resultVar} ${result} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

# Call it
GetSubList(SubListMatch ${HEADER_FILES})
```

When this code runs, `SubListMatch` will hold the matched elements.

You could improve the function by e.g. giving it an extra parameter for the directory name, so that others than `DirA` can be matched for:

```
function(GetSubList resultVar dirName)
  # as before, except the if()
    if(ITR MATCHES "(.*)${dirName}/(.*)")
  # same as before
endfunction()
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
file(GLOB DIRA_H_FILES DirA/*.cpp)
```

Comment: `DirA` might not actually exist on the system (yet). Lists of paths exist for lots of reasons. Globbing without `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` is a horrible practice and needs to be specifically justified in every case. Globbing even _with_ C-D is dubious.